# Problem copying NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, arrays

I am trying to copy one array to another:

```
NSMutableArray *itemsCopy = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.items copyItems:YES];
```

but I get the error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Item copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5a74900'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x025afc99 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x026fd5de objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x025b17ab -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x02521496 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x02521052 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x025108fa -[NSObject(NSObject) copy] + 42
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x025ab732 -[NSArray initWithArray:range:copyItems:] + 290
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x02513963 -[NSArray initWithArray:copyItems:] + 99
    8   MyViewController                          0x0000787d -[MyViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] + 258
    9   UIKit                               0x003968f8 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1140
    10  UIKit                               0x0038d1de -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtIndexPath:] + 219
    11  Foundation                          0x000a404e __NSFireDelayedPerform + 441
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x025910c3 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 19
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x02592704 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1364
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x024ef089 __CFRunLoopRun + 1817
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x024ee600 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x024ee521 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x02db52c8 GSEventRunModal + 217
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x02db538d GSEventRun + 115
    19  UIKit                               0x00332e8f UIApplicationMain + 1160
    20  MyViewController                          0x0000210c main + 102
    21  MyViewController                          0x0000209d start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make sure all the *contents* of `self.items` adopt the NSCopying protocol.

If you just want a shallow copy, send the `-mutableCopy` message to `self.items`.

```
NSMutableArray *itemsCopy = [self.items mutableCopy];
```

Comment: if I set copyItems:NO will it not copy the contents of self.items into the new array?

Comment: @Sheehan Alam: no it won't, but if your objects don't conform to the NSCopying protocol, that won't be possible anyway.

Comment: Curious, what is the point of copyItems:NO if it doesn't copy the objects into the new array? In what situation would you copy an array, but not its contents?

Comment: @Sheehan: If you pass `NO` the contents will be shared. But sometimes you just want to modify the list as a whole without touching the contents, e.g. copy a list of UIView subviews and sort it.

Comment: Sheeham Alam: `copyItems:YES` makes copies of the items, and initializes the new array with the copies, leaving the original items only in the original array (and wherever else they may be). With `copyItems:NO`, the new array is initialized to hold the same items as the original array.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide your classes with the `copyWithZone` selector (according to `NSCopying` protocol) if you are not copying objects that implement that protocol by default.

So if you are copying custom objects you have to implement it. The `copy` method always calls `copyWithZone`.. and you must always provide the implementation, it can't know what to copy inside objects by itself..