# How can I append objects to an NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have two arrays and I would like to append one to the end of the other. How can I go about doing this?

```
self.itemsCopy = [self.items mutableCopy];
```

Will copy the array, but I would like to append self.items.

Comment: Isn't this just an extension of your original question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976910/problem-copying-nsmutablearray

Comment: Joshua Nozzi: Nothing wrong with that. It is a separate question, regardless of its origins.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming `itemsCopy` is an `NSMutableArray` that has already been created, you can do:

```
[self.itemsCopy addObjectsFromArray:self.items];
```

Answer (score 5):

Check out the docs for `NSMutableArray`:

> [`addObjectsFromArray:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/addObjectsFromArray:)
>
> Adds the objects contained in another given array to the end of the receiver’s content.

(This won't be a deep copy, however)