# How to bind 2 NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, binding, nsmutablearray

i have 2 NSMutableArray with same type. i want to add second nsmutablearray to first one.

```
NSMutableArray *tmpArray1 (10 objects in it)

NSMutableArray *tmpArray2 (10 objects in it)
```

if i use `[tmpArray1 addobject:tmparray2];`  tmpArray1's count goes to 11.
but i want to append tmparray2 to firstone. count must be 20.

thanks...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I append objects to an NSMutableArray?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977122/how-can-i-append-objects-to-an-nsmutablearray)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[tmpArray1 addObjectsFromArray:tmparray2];
```

Answer (score 0):

[Use `-addObjectsFromArray:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/addObjectsFromArray:) to extend a array by another.

```
[tmpArray1 addObjectsFromArray:tmpArray2];
```